VS Code | How to remove Remote Tunnel Service
I tested the Remote Tunnel extension, including the Install as a Service option, but would now like to completely remove it, but cannot figure out how to remove the Remote Tunnel Service.
I disabled and then uninstalled extension, but the Remote Tunnel Service still exists and still establishes a tunnel every time I start up VS Code.
I tried renaming the code-tunnel.exe file, which obviously stops the tunnel from establishing, but it's a bit of a nasty solution.
See here, where you can see the extension is not installed but the Remote Tunnel Service is, and attempted to connect (but couldn't because I had renamed that file):

How do I get rid of that Remote Tunnel Service, please?
